# Start firefox selenium with proxy

Tags: node.js, selenium, proxy

I want to run selenium with proxy. I am using this command:

```
    .\java.exe -jar 'D:\Проекты\printscreen\selenium\selenium-2.33.0.jar' -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
```

but the above command is not working. So can anybody help me about how to run/use proxy in selenium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to switch to the directory where your jar is:

-`cd D:\Проекты\printscreen\selenium\selenium-2.33.0.jar`

Then start selenium jar with proxy:

- `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1`

For me it worked. See pic below:
[image]